# Mounting NTFS directory from within VMWare image

Tags: 11.10, ntfs, vmware

I'm running UBuntu 11.10 as a guest in VMWare Player on a WIndows 7 laptop and would like to mount an NTFS directory in UBuntu but not sure how to go about it.  All the directions I've found are written from the perspective that Linux is running in a dual-boot environment whereas from inside the guest environment I don't have any NTFS in fdisk.

`fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2610 cylinders, total 41943040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0008a459

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    40894463    20446208   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        40896510    41940991      522241    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        40896512    41940991      522240   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I was expecting to see an NTFS device though as I'd enabled shared folders in my virtual machine settings.  Can someone point me to to some info on the matter?

Comment: I have the same issue, the following command gives me the shared folders: `root@ubuntu:/usr/bin# vmware-hgfsclient` BUT, they are not mounted, and I have no hgfs folder. Also mounting the folder does not work.

Comment: Same here. I can not find it, and when I try to rerun `vmware-config-tools.pl` I get compile errors: `/tmp/vmware-root/modules/vmhgfs-only/filesystem.c:48:28: fatal error: linux/smp_lock.h: No such file or directory` Has anyone else seen this? I am running generic ubuntu 11.10 (64 bit) on VMware workstation 7.1.4 br

Comment: I never did fine a solution for the problem.  Ended up going to a dual-boot of Windows 7 and UBuntu 11.10 instead running UBuntu in VMWare.

Comment: work fine here on vmware workstation , on my laptop i have windows 7 running & ubuntu in vm ..share folders work's very well in vmware workstation 8 ....simple just share folder in vm tab ...

Answer (score 1):

Your shared folder will not show up as a drive or partition of your primary hard disc but rather it will be available (and already mounted for you, if you've installed the guest additions -- you *have* installed those, right?) elsewhere. See [this page](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_sharedfolder_viewing.html) for more information.